# Keyboard Layouts Plugin forgets settings, unable find workaround

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard-layout

I use Xubuntu. As [everyone knows](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=xubuntu%20%22Keyboard%20Layouts%20Plugin%22%20doesn%27t%20remember), Keyboard Layouts Plugin is very, very buggy and it still forgets my settings. It drives me crazy - I have to set them again and again every time I wake up or turn on my laptop.

So I found a solution - put into my `.bashrc` this:

```
setxkbmap -option '' -option grp:alt_shift_toggle cz,us -variant querty
```

That should set my toggle to Alt+shift and my layouts to **Czech QUERTY** and plain **US English** as a second one. Voilà, that seems to work! I could use Keyboard Layouts Plugin only as an indicator, that's okay.

However, it doesn't work well. The problem is that it ignores `-variant` setting. More or less. In Keyboard Layouts Plugin I actually see **Czech QUERTY** selected, but in reality my keyboard types **QUERTZ**. That's insane :-(

Could anyone help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the right answer is: **There is a typo.** It's not Q **U** ERTY, but Q **W** ERTY! I promise next time I'll ask at the morning, being fresh.

However, until I realized it's typo, I searched and experimented even more and I came up with a **different, less hackish solution**:

I found out there is a `/etc/default/keyboard` file with keyboard settings. If I edit it and then dare to touch Keyboard Layouts Plugin, my changes are preserved even after multiple restarts. No need for any hacks with `setxkbmap`.

I edited the file in a following way:

```
# Check /usr/share/doc/keyboard-configuration/README.Debian for
# documentation on what to do after having modified this file.

# The following variables describe your keyboard and can have the same
# values as the XkbModel, XkbLayout, XkbVariant and XkbOptions options
# in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="cz,us"
XKBVARIANT="qwerty"
XKBOPTIONS="grp:alt_shift_toggle"

# If you don't want to use the XKB layout on the console, you can
# specify an alternative keymap.  Make sure it will be accessible
# before /usr is mounted.
# KMAP=/etc/console-setup/defkeymap.kmap.gz
```

This works. Hope it helps someone!

See also:

- http://ubuntu.sabza.org/2006/10/13/xubuntu-easily-switch-keyboard-layout/
- http://blog.ssokolow.com/archives/2011/12/24/getting-your-way-with-setxkbmap/

Comment: It does not actually work for me. It only seemed to work. Follow up: http://askubuntu.com/questions/181254/is-there-a-way-to-completely-remove-particular-keyboard-layout-from-my-xubuntu