# Is there a way to completely remove particular keyboard layout from my Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard-layout

I have a problem with keyboard layouts in my Xubuntu. It's described in [my previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/177525/keyboard-layouts-plugin-forgets-settings-unable-find-workaround/177709). I tried many settings and special commands and it seemed to work (that is why I selected my previous question as solved), but then I realized every now and then (no idea when exactly and why) it switches to **Czech QWERTZ** again. After a while, it's back to Czech QWERTY. That's insane and totally against logic. My setting is **EN US / CZ QWERTY** everywhere.

I realized there is probably no peaceful solution. So I ask: **Is there a way to completely remove Czech QWERTZ keyboard layout from my computer**? Send it to a black hole at the opposite side of universe or something similar?